# C++ SetWindowsHookEx WH_KEYBOARD_LL Correct Setup

Tags: c++, key, capture, hook, setwindowshookex

I'm creating a console application in which I'd like to record key presses (like the UP ARROW). I've created a Low Level Keyboard Hook that is supposed to capture all Key Presses in any thread and invoke my callback function, but it isn't working. The program stalls for a bit when I hit a key, but never invokes the callback. I've checked the documentation but haven't found anything. I don't know whether I'm using SetWindowsHookEx() incorrectly (to my knowledge it successfully creates the hook) or my callback function is incorrect! I'm not sure whats wrong! Thanks in advance for the help.

```
#include "Windows.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

HHOOK hookHandle;

LRESULT CALLBACK keyHandler(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {

 hookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyHandler, NULL, 0);

 if(hookHandle == NULL) {
  cout << "ERROR CREATING HOOK: ";
  cout << GetLastError() << endl;
  getchar();
  return 0;
 }

 MSG message;

 while(GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0) != 0) {
  TranslateMessage( &message );
  DispatchMessage( &message );
 }

 cout << "Press any key to quit...";
 getchar();

 UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookHandle);

 return 0;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK keyHandler(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
 cout << "Hello!" << endl;

 // Checks whether params contain action about keystroke
 if(nCode == HC_ACTION) {
  cout << ((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *) lParam)->vkCode << endl;
 }

 return CallNextHookEx(hookHandle, nCode, 
            wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127112/global-keyboard-hook-not-working/2127292#2127292) for a similar question, which I answered that will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't block on a syscall (the getchar), you have to be running a window loop and processing messages before your hook gets called.

Comment: How would I implement a window loop? I'm very unfamiliar with WinAPIs (in fact whats the purpose of a window loop?)

Comment: Thanks, I'll post back in a couple minutes if I'm still having problems.

Comment: So basically a Message Loop sends the application queue's messages to the appropriate hooks?

I've got it working now! Thanks. The code I posted contains the fix.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows XP, you need, you need to pass `hInstance` (from `WinMain`) as the third argument to `SetWindowsHookEx`.  For example:

```
int WINAPI WinMain
( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow ) {

  hookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx ( WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyHandler, hInstance, 0 );

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest simle first;

// VB: Retrieve the applications instance
  HINSTANCE appInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

and then:
hookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyHandler, appInstance, 0);

// ..., but there are another errors later, too