# Why must SetWindowsHookEx be used with a windows message queue

Tags: c++, hook, message-queue

I've been trying some things with hooks, and I don't understand why hooks must be used with a message queue

```
hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardProc, NULL, 0);
MSG msg;
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
{
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);
```

Why doesn't something like this work ?

```
hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, KeyboardProc, NULL, 0);
cin >> aKey;
UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);
```

Using boost threads, and a barrier doesn't work either. Why can't the waiting between the hook and unhook be done in another manner ?

EDIT:

I did a mistake when I created this sample, I create a WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook, not WH_KEYBOARD, (I don't think it makes a big difference)

Also the loop never executes only waits on the GetMessage function.

The loop executes only when I post the quit message `PostThreadMessage(id, WM_QUIT, 2323, NULL);` so I don't understand what does it do beside waiting, is there some internal processing ?

RELATED:

[C++ SetWindowsHookEx WH_KEYBOARD_LL Correct Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166581/c-setwindowshookex-wh-keyboard-ll-correct-setup)

[How can I set up a CBT hook on a Win32 console window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199747/how-can-i-set-up-a-cbt-hook-on-a-win32-console-window)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The low-level hooks, WH_KEYBOARD_LL and WH_MOUSE_LL are different from all the other hooks.  They don't require a DLL to be injected into the target process.  Instead, Windows calls your hook callback directly, inside your own process.  To make that work, a message loop is required.  There is no other mechanism for Windows to make callbacks on your main thread, the callback can only occur when you've called Get/PeekMessage() so that Windows is in control.

A global hook like WH_KEYBOARD is very different.  It requires a DLL and the callback occurs within the process that processes the keyboard message.  You need some kind of inter-process communication to let your own program be aware of this.  Named pipes are the usual choice.  Which otherwise of course requires that this injected process pumps a message loop.  It wouldn't get keyboard messages otherwise.

Favor a low-level hook, they are *much* easier to get going.  But do pump or it won't work.  And beware of timeouts, if you're not responsive enough then Windows will kill your hook without notice.

[Understanding the low-level mouse and keyboard hook (win32)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3134183/#3134368)

Comment: So, If I understand this correctly, Windows can only call my callback while in a Get/PeekMessage() call ?

Comment: You understand it correctly.  There is no other way to safely inject calls into a thread, it has to be idle.  This is why message loops exist.

Comment: @HansPassant to clarify, are you suggesting that for global hooks like WH_KEYBOARD named pipes can be used to "pass" info back to my own program and that program does not need a message pump?

Comment: @HansPassant For WH_CALLWNDPROC hook is it mandatory to pump messages, in the hooking application? The procedure is inside a DLL though. Please help me as I am bit confused :(

Answer (score 3):

Windows Hooks hook the Windows message loop: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959#wh_keyboardhook

> The WH_KEYBOARD hook enables an application to monitor message traffic
>   for WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP messages about to be returned by the
>   GetMessage or PeekMessage function. You can use the WH_KEYBOARD hook
>   to monitor keyboard input posted to a message queue.

Console applications don't pump messages themselves - the console process does.  So it won't work unless the process has a message loop.

See:

[How can I set up a CBT hook on a Win32 console window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199747/how-can-i-set-up-a-cbt-hook-on-a-win32-console-window)

[C++ SetWindowsHookEx WH_KEYBOARD_LL Correct Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166581/c-setwindowshookex-wh-keyboard-ll-correct-setup)

Comment: thanks for the links, I went trough all of them but I still don't understand what GetMessage does beside waiting. In my case (console application) the only time it executes it when I post the quit message to the thread.

Comment: Also, since GetMessage waits, doesn't this mean that the console is not pumping any message till my quit message ?

Comment: See Han's answer - Windows will only call your thread back when it knows that its idle.  And if the thread is blocked in GetMesasge() Windows knows that it isn't doing anything