# How can I terminate a thread that has a seperate message loop?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-2007, message-loop

I am writing a utility unit for the `SetWindowsHookEx` API.

To use it, I'd like to have an interface like this:

```
var
  Thread: TKeyboardHookThread;
begin
  Thread := TKeyboardHookThread.Create(SomeForm.Handle, SomeMessageNumber);
  try
    Thread.Resume;
    SomeForm.ShowModal;
  finally
    Thread.Free; // <-- Application hangs here
  end;
end;
```

In my current implementation of `TKeyboardHookThread` I am unable to make the thread exit correctly.

The code is:

```
  TKeyboardHookThread = class(TThread)
  private
    class var
      FCreated                 : Boolean;
      FKeyReceiverWindowHandle : HWND;
      FMessage                 : Cardinal;
      FHiddenWindow            : TForm;
  public
    constructor Create(AKeyReceiverWindowHandle: HWND; AMessage: Cardinal);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

function HookProc(nCode: Integer; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
var
  S: KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;
begin
  if nCode < 0 then begin
    Result := CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam)
  end else begin
    S := PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT(lParam)^;
    PostMessage(TKeyboardHookThread.FKeyReceiverWindowHandle, TKeyboardHookThread.FMessage, S.vkCode, 0);
    Result := CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
  end;
end;

constructor TKeyboardHookThread.Create(AKeyReceiverWindowHandle: HWND;
  AMessage: Cardinal);
begin
  if TKeyboardHookThread.FCreated then begin
    raise Exception.Create('Only one keyboard hook supported');
  end;
  inherited Create('KeyboardHook', True);
  FKeyReceiverWindowHandle     := AKeyReceiverWindowHandle;
  FMessage                     := AMessage;
  TKeyboardHookThread.FCreated := True;
end;

destructor TKeyboardHookThread.Destroy;
begin
  PostMessage(FHiddenWindow.Handle, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TKeyboardHookThread.Execute;
var
  m: tagMSG;
  hook: HHOOK;
begin
  hook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, @HookProc, HInstance, 0);
  try
    FHiddenWindow := TForm.Create(nil);
    try
      while GetMessage(m, 0, 0, 0) do begin
        TranslateMessage(m);
        DispatchMessage(m);
      end;
    finally
      FHiddenWindow.Free;
    end;
  finally
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);
  end;
end;
```

AFAICS the hook procedure only gets called when there is a message loop in the thread. The problem is I don't know how to correctly exit this message loop.

I tried to do this using a hidden `TForm` that belongs to the thread, but the message loop doesn't process messages I'm sending to the window handle of that form.

How to do this right, so that the message loop gets terminated on thread shutdown?

Edit: The solution I'm now using looks like this (and works like a charm):

```
  TKeyboardHookThread = class(TThread)
  private
    class var
      FCreated                 : Boolean;
      FKeyReceiverWindowHandle : HWND;
      FMessage                 : Cardinal;
  public
    constructor Create(AKeyReceiverWindowHandle: HWND; AMessage: Cardinal);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

function HookProc(nCode: Integer; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
var
  S: KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;
begin
  if nCode < 0 then begin
    Result := CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam)
  end else begin
    S := PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT(lParam)^;
    PostMessage(TKeyboardHookThread.FKeyReceiverWindowHandle, TKeyboardHookThread.FMessage, S.vkCode, 0);
    Result := CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
  end;
end;

constructor TKeyboardHookThread.Create(AKeyReceiverWindowHandle: HWND;
  AMessage: Cardinal);
begin
  if TKeyboardHookThread.FCreated then begin
    raise Exception.Create('Only one keyboard hook supported');
  end;
  inherited Create('KeyboardHook', True);
  FKeyReceiverWindowHandle     := AKeyReceiverWindowHandle;
  FMessage                     := AMessage;
  TKeyboardHookThread.FCreated := True;
end;

destructor TKeyboardHookThread.Destroy;
begin
  PostThreadMessage(ThreadId, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TKeyboardHookThread.Execute;
var
  m: tagMSG;
  hook: HHOOK;
begin
  hook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, @HookProc, HInstance, 0);
  try
    while GetMessage(m, 0, 0, 0) do begin
      TranslateMessage(m);
      DispatchMessage(m);
    end;
  finally
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to send the WM_QUIT message to that thread's message queue to exit the thread. [GetMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns false if the message it pulls from the queue is WM_QUIT, so it will exit the loop on receiving that message.

To do this, use the [PostThreadMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to send the WM_QUIT message directly to the thread's message queue. For example:

```
PostThreadMessage(Thread.Handle, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

The message pump never exits and so when you free the thread it blocks indefinitely waiting for the Execute method to finish. Call PostQuitMessage, from the thread, to terminate the message pump. If you wish to invoke this from the main thread then you will need to post a WM_QUIT to the thread.

Also, your hidden window is a disaster waiting to happen. You can't create a VCL object outside the main thread. You will have to create a window handle using raw Win32, or even better, use DsiAllocateHwnd.

Comment: The window was just a "last resort", I tried various things before. I don't actually need a window handle.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff - but your message loop need a window handle; `DispatchMessage` dispatches a message to a window procedure, and `DSiAllocateHWND` is the best method to create this procedure

Comment: @Serg Actually it doesn't need a window handle, everything works fine without one. The only purpose of the message loop is to give Windows a chance to call the hook procedure. Is there a way to use a Windows Hook Without a message loop?

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff I don't know about hooks, never used them. If you have no window (handle) created in a thread I see no purpose of standard message loop cause what it does is dispatches a message to a window procedure (using window handle to find destination window).

Comment: @Serg I'm only using a hook here to work around another problem, but that's a different story. About the message loop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458807/why-must-setwindowshookex-be-used-with-a-windows-message-queue