# java call Hook by jna/ jni failed

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, hook, jna

I need to disable the mouse and keyboard input globally, but using pure java couldn't do the trick.

I chose jni/jna call c++ function. When I call a c++ function through jna, java program has no effect, without any error or exception.

I have tested the .dll file, in c++ it can't run perfectly.

Here is my java code:

```
public class HookTest {
    public interface  Hook extends Library{
        Hook INSTANCE = (Hook) Native.loadLibrary("lib/Hook",Hook.class);
        public void FuncEndHook();
        public void FuncHookDevice();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hook.INSTANCE.FuncHookDevice();
    }
}
```

my c++ code:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"

HHOOK g_HookHwnd = NULL;
HHOOK g_hMouse = NULL;

// 钩子子程
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK MyHookFun(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    printf("in hook key function\n");
    // 这个Structure包含了键盘的信息
    /*typedef struct {
    DWORD vkCode;
    DWORD scanCode;
    DWORD flags;
    DWORD time;
    ULONG_PTR dwExtraInfo;
    } KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT, *PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;*/
    // 我们只需要那个vkCode
    PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT pVirKey = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;

    // MSDN说了,nCode < 0的时候别处理
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        // 按键消息
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
        case WM_KEYUP:
        case WM_SYSKEYUP:
            switch (pVirKey->vkCode)
            {
            case VK_LWIN:
            case VK_RWIN:
                return 1;  // 吃掉消息
                break;
            }
            return 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(g_HookHwnd, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK  MyHookMouse(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    printf("in hook mouse function\n");
    return 1;
}


HMODULE g_Module;
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport)  BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    {

        break;
    }
    }
    return TRUE;
}


extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void FuncHookDevice()
{
    if (!g_HookHwnd)
    {
        printf("start hook\n");
        g_HookHwnd = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, MyHookFun, g_Module, 0);
        //g_hMouse = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MyHookMouse, g_Module, 0);  //暂时禁用鼠标钩子
    }
}

extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void FuncEndHook()
{
    printf("end hook\n");
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(g_HookHwnd);
    //UnhookWindowsHookEx(g_hMouse);   //暂时禁用鼠标钩子
    g_HookHwnd = NULL;
}
```

running result:

[image: result]

The program executed the c++, but did not disable the keyboard.

Thanks for reading and for your help.

Comment: Is everything 64-bit or 32-bit?  Remember that on a 64-bit system you will need 2 hooks one for 64-bit and one for 32-bit (and 2 instances of your Java program as 64-bit can not call 32-bit and visa-versa).

Comment: You need a message loop to listen to the keyboard events: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7458807/996081

Comment: Yes, everything is 64-bit. When i added a message loop,my question solved.And i find it would be better to add a single thread to control the hook.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out what the remarks section of the [`LowLevelKeyboardProc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985.aspx) callback function says:

> This hook is called in the context of the thread that installed it. The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook. Therefore, the thread that installed the hook must have a message loop.

You've created a hook for an event, but there's no *message loop* processing those events. All Windows applications that use events, such as graphical desktop applications which use native Windows styles, have a message loop which calls `GetMessage` to get events and act accordingly.

You could manually call the WinAPI functions to handle the message loop (`GetMessage`, `DispatchMessage`, etc.), but I'm happy to say that **JNA does have a helper for this**.

In the `jna-platform` package (you'll need to add that to your Maven/Gradle/whatever dependencies), there's a class named [`User32Util.MessageLoopThread`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.5.1/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/User32Util.MessageLoopThread.html).

The following example works for me:

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32Util.MessageLoopThread;

public class HookTest {

    public interface Hook extends Library {
        Hook INSTANCE = (Hook) Native.loadLibrary("lib/Hook", Hook.class);
        public void FuncEndHook();
        public void FuncHookDevice();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MessageLoopThread thread = new MessageLoopThread();
        thread.start();
        thread.runOnThread(() -> {
            Hook.INSTANCE.FuncHookDevice();
            return null;
        });
    }
}
```

Notice I'm explicitly calling `FuncHookDevice` on a new thread which is the same thread as the message loop, as required by the remarks.

Comment: Thank you. After I added message loop in c++,program can run perfectly.Also, I found that if I using jna ,I even don`t need write c++ code. There is the example in jna.[example](https://github.com/bigding/jna/blob/master/contrib/w32keyhook/com/sun/jna/contrib/demo/KeyHook.java)